# accessing tuple with tuple as elements in C++

Tags: c++

How can I access tuple with tuple as element using get?

```
vector<tuple<string, int, vector<tuple<string, int, string>>>> setOfWord
```

if I use tuple with pair as element,

```
vector <tuple<string, int, vector<pair<string, string>>>> setOfWord
```

I can access the elements by using

```
if( wordVector ==  (get<2>(setOfWord[i]))[j].second)
```

but how can I retrieve the inside element if I use tuple instead of pair ?

Thank you

Comment: Just `std::get` it again?

Comment: Have you tried `std::get<0>(std::get<2>(setOfWord[0])[0]);`?

Comment: Okay that solve problem. Thank you for helping and sorry for idiot question, stil new to C++.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <tuple> // for swap() and tuple 

using namespace std; 

int main() {
  vector<tuple<string, int, vector<tuple<string, int, string>>>> setOfWord;
  tuple <string,int,string> tup1("20",1,"17.5"); 
  vector< tuple <string,int,string>> v;
  v.push_back(tup1);
  tuple<string, int, vector<tuple<string, int, string>>> vt("str", 2, v);
  setOfWord.push_back(vt);
  cout<<get<0>(get<2>(setOfWord[0])[0]);

}
```